# items_wrap not working

Tags: php, menus, navigation, user-registration

I registered a wordpress menu this way:

```
function nothing_register_menus() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'nothing_register_menus' );
```

I am calling wp_nav_menu that way:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                'container' => false,
                'echo' => false,
                'menu_class' => 'nav-menu horiz-menu container',
                'items_wrap' => '<ul class="sixteen columns">%3$s</ul>'
            ) )
```

But the output always looks the same. The menu class is correct, but the wrapping ul never has a class.

Comment: how do you see the menu output for the above code if you use  `'echo' => false`?

Comment: I'm using a variable $output and echo the whole thing in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in your use `'menu_class'` and `'items_wrap'` not synchronized.

You can edit :

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                'container' => '',
                'echo' => '0',
                'menu_class' => 'nav-menu horiz-menu container sixteen columns',
                'items_wrap' => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
            ) )
```

or:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                'container' => '',
                'echo' => '0',
                'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav-menu horiz-menu container sixteen columns">%3$s</ul>'
            ) )
```

Apologize for my English is bad !

Answer (score 3):

Straight from [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Parameters):

> $items_wrap (string) (optional) Evaluated as the format string
>   argument of a sprintf() expression. The format string incorporates the
>   other parameters by numbered token. %1$s is expanded to the value of
>   the 'menu_id' parameter, %2$s is expanded to the value of the
>   'menu_class' parameter, and %3$s is expanded to the value of the list
>   items. If a numbered token is omitted from the format string, the
>   related parameter is omitted from the menu markup. Default: %3$s

Therefore your `items_wrap` should look like this:

```
'items_wrap' => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
```

where `%2$s` will be replaced by 'nav-menu horiz-menu container'.

I don't know where you expect the 'sixteen columns' classes to render.

Comment: That returns an ul without a class, too. In my understanding, it should be possible to add a custom class somehow. Just like the way is done here with the ID: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/menu-ul-class